How to add time access rule with ufw in Linux?
Does any1 knows if it is possible to add time rule access using ufw ? So far i have found out that it is possible with iptables as shown below but it is possible with ufw:
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.20  -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m time --timestart 15:00 --timestop 18:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun -j ACCEPT

Regards

I dont believe you can, judging by UFW man page. There is a reason why UFW stands for Uncomplicated FireWall.

Thanks @LasseMichaelMølgaard. I was reading ufw man page but i thought that maybe i was missing something. Anyway thanks for comment.

Note that ufw does support manually creating  custom rules for usecases where there is no native ufw syntax / functionality (yet) https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall#Advanced_Functionality

Searching a bit online. I was hoping it was possible to make an application rule where you could define before and after rules to an individual app profile. Because adding the rules directly to /etc/ufw/before.rule or /etc/ufw/after.rules seems a bit ugly in my book and not as easily managed as just turning on or off an application.
